# Checkout Page not loading and getting blank page

Tags: magento2, checkout, code

first, I apologize for not being a programmer and not being able to publicly post the URL in question.

The checkout process gets empty in the second process page.

I assume Initialization code laods in the wrong order.

It would be nice if I could send the URL as a PM and that someone finds out the cause of the problem with a debugger (or DevTools). Please write me a PM.

http://s18.directupload.net/images/190519/4cpt9rfc.jpg 
http://s18.directupload.net/images/190519/hmp5tj4b.jpg

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: check error log